# Kafka large message configuration

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I read many topics about configuration and I still don't understand.

when I do:

```
../kafka_2.11-1.1.0/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic my_topic --config max.message.bytes=10000000
```

this helps

but in my application a tried everything

```
def producerSettings(system: ActorSystem): ProducerSettings[String, KafkaMessage] =
    ProducerSettings(system, new StringSerializer, new GenericSerde[KafkaMessage].serializer())
      .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
      .withProperty("auto.create.topics.enable", "true")
      .withProperty("replica.fetch.max.bytes", maxSize)
      .withProperty("message.max.bytes", maxSize)

val producer: KafkaProducer[String, KafkaMessage] = configuration.producerSettings(context.system)
    .withBootstrapServers("localhost:" + config.getInt("kafka.port"))
    .withProperty("message.max.bytes", maxSize)
    .withProperty("max.request.size", maxSize)
    .createKafkaProducer()
```

when i start clean kafka - i see in logs

```
INFO Created log for partition my_topic-0 in /tmp/kafka-logs with properties {compression.type -> producer, message.format.version ->
1.1-IV0, file.delete.delay.ms -> 60000, max.message.bytes -> 1000012, min.compaction.lag.ms -> 0, message.timestamp.type -> CreateTime, min.insync.replicas -> 1, segment.jitter.ms -> 0, preallocate -> false, min.cleanable.dirty.ratio -> 0.5, index.interval.bytes -> 4096, unclean.leader.election.enable -> false, retention.bytes -> -1, delete.retention.ms -> 86400000, cleanup.policy -> [delete], flush.ms
-> 9223372036854775807, segment.ms -> 604800000, segment.bytes -> 1073741824, retention.ms -> 604800000, message.timestamp.difference.max.ms -> 9223372036854775807, segment.index.bytes -> 10485760, flush.messages -> 9223372036854775807}. (kafka.log.LogManager)
```

a you see `max.message.bytes` -> 1000012 still at default value
and i have to large record message exception again

what i am doing wrong? I want do configuration by my application - not console command. Is it possible?

Comment: You need to set a property on the broker, not only the producer... The broker is configured to only accept a max size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because your topic is auto created by the broker. When a topic gets created using the auto creation by the broker, it uses default config of the broker.

You can either change the default config in the broker which is `message.max.bytes` but I would not recommend that as the broker config would apply to all the other topics auto created.

Or you can create the topic explicitly in your application with the desired config so that broker won't create the topic automatically with its default config.